# Throws file not found Exceptions

Tags: java, android, andengine

I created a gfx folder inside an android project's assets folder. I stored images which i will be using in my game for android. Since i need to pass the image height and image width converting it to the nearest highest powwer of 2 in andEngine, so i create a ImageUtility class to read image inside the gfx folder and get its height and width.

```
package org.ujjwal.androidGameUtility;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class ImageUtilities {
    private static final String ABSOLUTE_PATH = "F:\\Games\\TowerOfHanoi\\assets\\gfx\\";
    private String fileName = "";
    private File imageFile;
    private int imageHeight;
    private int imageWidth;

    public ImageUtilities(String filename){

        this.fileName = filename;
        this.imageFile = new File(ABSOLUTE_PATH + this.fileName);

        try {
            processImage();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * this methods set the doucment relative path for the graphics to be used
     * and it is mandotry to call before using ImageUtilties object else it will throw filenotFoundException
     * 
     * @param path
     */ 

    private void  processImage() throws FileNotFoundException{
        if(imageFile.exists()){
            try {
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(this.imageFile);
                this.imageWidth = image.getWidth();
                this.imageHeight = image.getHeight();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else{
             throw new FileNotFoundException("Either you missed typed filename or haven't called setAssetBasePathMethod setImageBasePath(String path) method");
        }
    }

    public int getImageHeight(){
        return this.imageHeight;
    }
    public int getImageWidth(){
        return this.imageWidth;
    }

    public String getFileName(){
        return this.fileName;
    }

    public File getImageFile(){
        return this.imageFile;
    }
}
```

I always get FileNotFoundException with the error msg above. The weird problem is when i access the image file from other java class i don't get any error. I printed the height and width all went exactly i wanted but i could not access the same image file from my android game project. What kind of error is this. I provided absolute filepath for the image. I also tried to compare the file path they were same. Please tell me what error i got, I spend whole day trying to figure out but ...

Comment: Do you really not understand what `FileNotFoundException` means?  It literally tells you that the file is not found.  Check that your path is correct.

Comment: please read my note i can access the file from other java class i provided and absolute file path but i am not able to access from my android game project . it throws file not found exception but not when i access from other java class

Comment: @willnotquit I did read your note...it doesn't change the fact that `FileNotFoundException` means that it cannot find the file.

Comment: I got what file not FileNotFoundExcepton is but i can access the file from other java class with no exception but i cannot access the same file from android project... it means the same absolute file path is throwing an error when access from android projects java class but not when accessing from other java class.
Please try to answer my problem not what FileNotFoundException is

Comment: You literally asked `what kind of error is this`. How do you expect an Android device to read from your Windows `F` drive?

Comment: That is my workspace folder for my android project.

Comment: Yeah that path is wrong then.  Android cannot access the Windows file system like that.  You have to change the path to be relative to the Android device.

Comment: Also,  on another topic, why don't you create texture regions? You wouldn't need to resize to power of two or anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @mittmemo mentioned was right, you cannot access the F drive from your phone or emulator. Your computer and android are two different OS. What you can do is instead of putting your file in /assets, you can put it in /raw under resource directory. You can then access it by using:

```
try {
      Resources res = getResources();
      InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.yourfile);

      byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
      in_s.read(b);
      String str = new String(b);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, "File Reading Error", e);
 }
```