# Android Studio - Web View Error - No Such File or directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I am using Andoid Studio to develop an app and while opening the app , I am not able to see my web page ,a white screen is coming. I saw the console and find this error

```
E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

When I see my manifest file, its seems fine for me and also MainActivity.java seems good for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pe.com.bcp.creaapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Here is the java class

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        //myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String filePath = "file:///android_asset/Flickular-Demo-master/src/index.html";
        myWebView.loadUrl(filePath);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I do not understand why Its not showing and what I am missing ?

Activity Main Layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myWebView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the log from Console :-

```
09-04 13:38:20.307  10194-10194/ D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
09-04 13:38:20.318  10194-10194/ E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14035: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14039: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13936: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 401: 

Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 423: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
09-04 13:38:20.327  10194-10194/ D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
09-04 13:38:20.379  10194-10199 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 182K, 3% free 10944K/11207K, paused 15ms+0ms, total 17ms
09-04 13:38:20.928  10194-10201/ I/jdwp﹕ Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
09-04 13:38:21.233  10194-10194/ I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-04 13:38:21.233  10194-10194/ D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: where do you have the index.html in your project

Comment: I think you have the same problem with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31080399/4516174

Comment: @r7v I have the index.html inside asset folder, I have another folder Flickular-Demo-master/src inside that i have put it.

Comment: try putting the file directly under assets folder

Comment: I tried and still the same issues.

Comment: can you post the activity_main layout

Comment: @yongsunCN I have already put files inside my ANdroid project Asset Folder, So What I am reading in the link that I can't access external disk, but seems that not relevant to me. Please rectify me if I am wrong .

Comment: whats the path of your asset folder? It should be under the main folder

Comment: Yes it is under main folder and I have updated the Activity XML in the main question section. Please have a look..

Comment: I am trying by putting index.html directly to Asset folder , as I have tried only putting in another folder like www. Give me a moment and I will let you know the result. @r7v

Comment: NO Luck Still not working by directly putting index.html in asset folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88830/discussion-between-s-k-t-and-r7v).